Expected value in dice game with a 20 sided fair die
Question: You play a game with a 20 sided fair die. The game consists of 100 rounds. In each round you can toss the die or choose to draw money equal to the face value of the die on the table. If you choose to not roll, you can keep drawing money equal to the face value of the die for all the remaining turns. You play this game with the strategy that you will roll till you get a 19 or a 20 and then not roll again and draw money till the end of all the 100 rounds. For example, if you toss 2,15,12,19 on rounds 1 - 4, you can choose to draw 19 from rounds 5 - 100 thereby making your winnings 1824. What are your expected winnings with this strategy?
Solution:
Given solution: The expected number of rounds before getting a 19 or a 20 is 10. Therefore, the expected winnings is 19.5*90 = 1755.
This makes complete sense intuitively. However, I want to formalize this and solve for it as an exercise. I'm having trouble doing that.
Attempt:
My first thought was to define an rv $N = n$ which is the event that the first 19 or 20 rolls on the nth roll and use conditioning. However, I'm not sure if this is even a valid rv to define. For example, if over the course of all the hundred rolls I never roll a 19 or 20 then to what number would that event "Never rolling 19 or 20 in 100 turns" in the sample space be mapped by the rv N? If we choose to define N such that it does not map the event "Never rolling 19 or 20 in 100 turns", then the sum of the probability over n = 1-100 will not equal 1.
How do I do formalize the solution procedure to calculate the expected winnings without brute forcing it by writing out the probability for each event in the sample space and finding the expected winnings?
Thank you for answering.

If your strategy is to continue rolling until the first $19$ or $20$ is observed, then the number of times you roll is a right-truncated geometric random variable $X$ with parameter $p = 0.1$, which represents the probability of getting $19$ or $20$ on a single roll:
$$\Pr[X = x] = \begin{cases}(1-p)^{x-1} p, & x \in \{1,2,3, \ldots, 99\} \\ 
(1-p)^{99}, & x = 100. \end{cases} \tag{1}$$
The reason for the truncation is that you may roll the die at most $100$ times, and if you do roll the die $100$ times, on the last round, it does not matter whether you got $19$ or $20$; there are no more turns.  This is the literal interpretation of your strategy, although in practice, if you did not get a $19$ or $20$ for $99$ turns, you would want to not roll on the final $100^{\rm th}$ turn and take whatever amount of money is indicated by the outcome of the $99^{\rm th}$ roll.
In any case, if $X$ has the above probability distribution $(1)$, then the total winnings is the variable
$$W = (100 - X)(19 + B), \tag{2}$$
where $B \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ with $\Pr[B = 0] = \Pr[B = 1] = 0.5$, since the value of the final die roll is $19$ or $20$ with equal probability, and is independent of $X$.  Note that $W = 0$ if $X = 100$.  Thus
$$\operatorname{E}[W] = \operatorname{E}[(100-X)(19+B)] = (100 - \operatorname{E}[X])(19 + \operatorname{E}[B]) = 19.5(100 - \operatorname{E}[X]). \tag{3}$$
To compute $\operatorname{E}[X]$, we can perform the computation
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{x=1}^{100} x \Pr[X = x] = \frac{1-(1-p)^{100}}{p} \approx 9.999734386. \tag{4}$$
This result makes intuitive sense, because if you could roll an unlimited number of times, the expected number of rolls you would need to observe the first $19$ or $20$ is just $1/p = 10$.  Since you are guaranteed to stop by the $100^{\rm th}$ roll, but the probability of needing to roll this many times is very small, the expected value of the truncated number of rolls is slightly less.  Consequently,
$$\operatorname{E}[W] \approx 1755.005179.$$  Note that this is not exactly $1755$ as claimed, again due to the truncation of $X$.
This is by no means the optimal strategy.  A question for the reader is, what would be a better strategy?  What are the expected winnings if the threshold for stopping is the first observation of a roll that is at least $v$ for each $v \in \{1, \ldots, 20\}$?  The expectation we calculated above was for the strategy $v = 19$.

An improved strategy would be to have the threshold to stop decrease with the number of turns remaining.  Intuitively you don't have as many turns left for the improved draw/turn to make a difference, so you should take what you can get.  You clearly should not roll on the 100th turn.  On the 99th you should keep anything 6 or above because you will draw 12 instead of the average 10.5 you get from rolling.

@RossMillikan Indeed, I had the same thought.  Interestingly, the computation under the decision rule I mentioned in my answer shows that it is best (in terms of expectation) to stop rolling if you get a value of at least $18$.  But I agree that varying the threshold as a function of the number of die rolls remaining would be even better, although I haven't given much thought to how one should choose such a function.

I did the calculation for a six sided die and (I think) 20 rolls but can't find it.  You started off accepting only 6, then 5 and so on.

@heropup How is B a valid random variable here? The sample space would contain the events: "19 was rolled first" , "20 was rolled first", "Neither 19 nor 20 rolled in 100 turns". How can we assign this to a Bernoulli rv?

@AshwinSahasranaman Think of it this way.  Suppose I roll a fair six-sided die until I first see a $5$ or a $6$, at which point I stop.  What is the distribution of the value of the last die roll?  It must be equally likely to see $5$ or $6$.  As for the value of $B$ if neither $19$ or $20$ is rolled in $X = 100$ turns, it doesn't matter--the value of $W = (100 - 100)(19 + B) = 0.$

$N$, the count for rolls before the first favoured result (19 or 20), is a truncated geometric random variable.
We want $N$ to equal $100$ when the terminating event for a geometric distributed counter does not occur before the last (one hundredeth) roll.
So, we let $G\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(1/10)$ be the count for rolls before a 19 or 20 shows, then we set:
$$\begin{align}N&=\begin{cases}G &:& 0\leq G\leq 99\\100&:& 100\leq G\end{cases}\\[4ex]\mathsf P(N=n) &= \mathsf P(G=n)\mathbf 1_{0\leq n\lt 99}+\mathsf P(G\geq n)\mathbf 1_{n=100}\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{9^{n}}{10^{n+1}}\mathbf 1_{0\leq n\leq 99}+\dfrac{9^{100}}{10^{100}}\mathbf 1_{n=100}\end{align}$$
And so assuredly, $\displaystyle\mathsf P(0\leq N\leq 100) = \mathsf P(0\leq G) = 1 $

Let $X$ be your earnings.  You expect to earn $(20+19)/2$ each turn after you stop rolling, for 100 turns.
$$\mathsf E(X) =\mathsf E(19.5 (100-N))\\ = 1950-19.5\,\mathsf E(N)$$
So, having found $\mathsf E(N) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{100} n~\mathsf P(N=n) =10$ ...

I don't understand how you expect to earn 19/2 in each turn before you stop rolling. Could you please explain?

Oh.  I see that it's "or" rather than "and".  Thank you, @AshwinSahasranaman
